# Do I need an apply in a $scope.$on?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I`m using angular 1.4.

I have a watchGroup in my scope:

```
    $scope.$watchGroup(
        ["scroll_top", "tokeninput_has_focus"],
        function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {
            console.log("WATCH");        
        }
    );
```

And I change the $scope.scroll_top variable in an event:

Out of the scope function:

```
restegourmetApp.directive("scroll", function ($window) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
            scope.$broadcast("onWindowScroll", $window);
        });
    };
});
```

Inside the scope function:

```
    $scope.$on('onWindowScroll', function(scope, element, attrs) { 
        $scope.scroll_top = $window.scrollY;
        console.log("SCROLL");
    });
```

But the watchGroup function is not executed, when I scroll, console outputs "SCROLL" but not "WATCH".

I need to change it to

```
    $scope.$on('onWindowScroll', function(scope, element, attrs) { 
        $scope.scroll_top = $window.scrollY;
        $scope.$apply();
        console.log("SCROLL");
    });
```

to trigger the watch function-

I do not understand this? I thought I was inside the scope with $scope.$on.

There must be something I do not understand, can somebody help me?

Thank you!

Comment: You should be not "inside scope" you should be inside angular's $digest loop. Which is obviously not when `onWindowScroll` handler is executed. Also the syntax is not correct. `$apply()` accepts a function or null. This code is equivalent to `$scope.scroll_top = $window.scrollY; $scope.$apply();`

Comment: Thank you. I edited my post to show, that the event bind is not done inside scope. I broadcast the onWindowScroll in a directive. And I need to call $scope.apply inside the scope function. And I don`t understand why I have to do this.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle hope this helps to understand what a $digest cycle is and how it affects bindings